# Как сделать update sql запросом из другой таблицы?

Tags: sql

Есть таблицы:

`Таблица 1
Поле 1_1
Поле 2_1`

`Таблица 2
Поле 1_2
Поле 2_2`

Надо сделать `update Поле 2_1` Таблицы 1 из `Поля 2_2`, Таблицы 2

Answer (score 9):

```
Update Таблица_1 
set Поле_2_1 =
(select Поле_2_2 from Таблица_2 where Поле_1_1 = Поле_1_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update Таблица_1
set Поле_2_1 = Таблица_2.Поле_2_2
from Таблица_2
where Таблица_2.Поле_1_2 = Таблица_1.Поле_1_1
```

Comment: FROM в операторе update поддерживается далеко не всеми СУБД, т.к. не является стандартной конструкцией.